# Why my Power BI Line Chart Forecast is overlapping?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, forecasting, forecast

I'm working with a Power BI forecast and I'm trying to create a forecast from today till the beginning of January 2024.

Because we are in August 2023 and I want to reach January 2023 I setup 150 days in the future, so far so good:

[image]

But now I want my forecast from September 2023 to January 2024 to be **based** on the data from September 2022 to January 2023.

In order to do so I  change my timeline and I just cover from September 2022 to January 2023. But now the forecast is covering only the next 150 so that means from February 2023 till around June 2023:

[image]

This is unnecessary because I have those data. So I use the feature `Ignore the last` and I set 210 days and I change the timeline again to keep all the data till August 2023. Now the forecast overlaps:

[image]

So how can I create a forecast form September 2023 to January 2024 based on the data from September 2022 to January 2023.

It seems so simple but it's not.